# Retrieving Position X,Y for Three Images

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies but I haven't found what I needed from other threads OR I just couldn't use what they had.

afternoon
was hoping to get an answer to an annoying problem I'm having
I need these values to work from; as in dynamically. So, I can have a variable with the X position constantly updated and also have the original stored earlier.

http://postimage.org/image/q8h41o7f9/full/

- the offset values of an image, but I need them for 3 images

I get this error
 http://postimage.org/image/5drn1ubo7/

no point in saying I'm a newb, but go easy and explain as if you would a child.

Comment: This question is very unclear. I suggest using the "edit" link, remove extraneous things, and add in hard information and examples of your markup and code.

Comment: I feel like I've just read a SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error you have received, it looks like you're using `offsetTop()` (i.e. as a function), rather than `offsetTop` (as a property of the element object)...

You should try:

```
topPos = element.offsetTop;
```

See here for more information > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetTop

Comment: thanks for the replies.

BenM: you're right. thank you very much. I thought I needed the brackets to hold the value.